# Passing more than one parameter to an anonymous function in R

Tags: r, function, anonymous

Why doesn't this work?  or is just the way R works?

Thanks
JJ

```
    a <- c(1,2,3)
    b <- 5
    lapply(a, function(x) print(x))  # works

    lapply(a, function(x,b) print(b)) # doesn't work.

    I get --
     Error in FUN(c(1, 2, 3)[[1L]], ...) : 
       argument "b" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 3):

`lapply` only passes one argument on, because it's only designed to have one argument vary.  If you just want to pass extra arguments along, put them as additional options to `lapply`:

```
lapply(a, function(x,y) print(y), y=b)
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 5
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

From the `lapply` help file:

> ...   optional arguments to FUN.

If you want more than one varying argument to be passed to your function, look at `mapply`.

Comment: This relies on b being in the Global environment as well.  It's not any different that the second solution I gave except a shifting of what you put where.  And generally we're working on objects from the glob. env. so it's expected that b would come from there.

Comment: To illustrate what I mean think of your solution like this: `lapply(a, function(x,y) print(y), y=b)`.  See how it's basically the same thing as my #2.  It's probably better for readability not to call the arguments to the anonymous function the same thing as the object passed to it though you can.

Comment: Hm.  You're right that the two cases are not as different as I'd thought initially.  I still think that passing it using lapply's `...` is a bit more proper than passing it using the default of the anonymous function.

Comment: And I agree about not using the same name for both aiding at very least it's explanatory power.

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting a and b together in a list as follows:

```
lapply(list(a, b), function(x) print(b))
```

or specifying an argumant to pass b to as in:

```
lapply(a, function(x, y=b) print(y))
```

But I'm not really sure what you're after.